# Pivot Table Showing Number of "Open" Records by Hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I effectively have a table with two important fields. ReadyDate and CompleteDate.

I want my output to give me 24 columns, corresponding with an hour of the day, each giving me the number of records that were still "open" (defined as ReadyDate before the end of the hour but CompleteDate after the end of an hour) during that clock hour.

So the trick is that one record can appear in zero or more columns. Something that was ReadyDate at 6:05am and CompleteDate 9:17am would appear on the 6:00a, 7:00a and 8:00a column.

So if the table has the following entries

```
10-14-2019 06:05   10-14-2019 06:10    (this will populate no columns)
10-14-2019 07:12   10-14-2019 09:30    (this will populate the 7:00 hour and 8:00 hour)
10-14-2019 10:02   10-14-2019 13:55    (this will populate the 10:00 hour, 11:00, 12:00)
10-14-2019 12:50   10-14-2019 15:30    (this will populate the 12:00, 13:00, 14:00)
```

I'd expect my output to have 24 columns with the following numbers
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0

I am at a loss as to how to proceed. Any insights would be appreciated

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT-CORRECTED for SHIFT OF 1 HOUR***

Here is a PIVOT option which uses an ad-hoc tally table.

The roll over midnight is accounted for.

Not clear if you wanted rows by date.  If not, it would be a small matter to remove.

**Example**

```
;with cte1 as (
    Select Date  = convert(date,D) 
          ,Item  = datepart(hour,D)
          ,Value = 1
     From  YourTable A
     Cross Apply (
                    Select Top (DateDiff(HOUR,ReadyDate,CompleteDate)+0) 
                           D=DateAdd(HOUR,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),ReadyDate) 
                     From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
                  ) B
),  cte2 as ( 
    Select Date
          ,B.Item 
          ,B.Value
     From  (Select distinct Date from cte1 ) a
     Cross Join (Select Top 24 Item=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)),Value=0 From master..spt_values n1 ) B
)
Select *
 From  (Select * from cte1
        Union All
        Select * from cte2
        ) src
 Pivot (sum(Value) for Item in ([0] ,[1] ,[2] ,[3] ,[4] ,[5] ,[6] ,[7] ,[8] ,[9] ,[10],[11],
                                [12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Your solution is awesome and I appreciate it a lot. I am still working through the example and think I understand most of it. I did have to add my own table populated with values 0 through 23 as I don't have access to the master database. However, it works extremely well.

I am trying to understand the first cross apply. Somehow it is using the values table twice. I broke apart this part into a separate select to understand it. It works, but I don't competely follow the logic. Can you please explain?

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln Happy it helped.   CTE1 will "expand" each row via an ad-hoc tally/numbers table.   CTE2 will create a dummy list of all combinations of dates and hours ... this is a little cheat to avoid NULL values in the final PIVOT.    The final select is a simple PIVOT of cte1 and cte2

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln I should add... WELL DONE on taking the initiative to break it down,   This is how we learn  :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the prettiest but it does work as you explained.  I would love to see a more elegant solution if anyone has one.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    date1 DATETIME NOT NULL,
    date2 DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @t
(
    date1,
    date2
)
VALUES
('10-14-2019 06:05', '10-14-2019 06:10'),
('10-14-2019 07:12', '10-14-2019 09:30'),
('10-14-2019 10:02', '10-14-2019 13:55'),
('10-14-2019 12:50', '10-14-2019 15:30');

SELECT SUM(t.[0]) AS [0],
       SUM(t.[1]) AS [1],
       SUM(t.[2]) AS [2],
       SUM(t.[3]) AS [3],
       SUM(t.[4]) AS [4],
       SUM(t.[5]) AS [5],
       SUM(t.[6]) AS [6],
       SUM(t.[7]) AS [7],
       SUM(t.[8]) AS [8],
       SUM(t.[9]) AS [9],
       SUM(t.[10]) AS [10],
       SUM(t.[11]) AS [11],
       SUM(t.[12]) AS [12],
       SUM(t.[13]) AS [13],
       SUM(t.[14]) AS [14],
       SUM(t.[15]) AS [15],
       SUM(t.[16]) AS [16],
       SUM(t.[17]) AS [17],
       SUM(t.[18]) AS [18],
       SUM(t.[19]) AS [19],
       SUM(t.[20]) AS [20],
       SUM(t.[21]) AS [21],
       SUM(t.[22]) AS [22],
       SUM(t.[23]) AS [23]
FROM
(
    SELECT id,
           date1,
           date2,
           CASE
               WHEN 0
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [0],
           CASE
               WHEN 1
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [1],
           CASE
               WHEN 2
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [2],
           CASE
               WHEN 3
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [3],
           CASE
               WHEN 4
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [4],
           CASE
               WHEN 5
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [5],
           CASE
               WHEN 6
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [6],
           CASE
               WHEN 7
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [7],
           CASE
               WHEN 8
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [8],
           CASE
               WHEN 9
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [9],
           CASE
               WHEN 10
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [10],
           CASE
               WHEN 11
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [11],
           CASE
               WHEN 12
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [12],
           CASE
               WHEN 13
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [13],
           CASE
               WHEN 14
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [14],
           CASE
               WHEN 15
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [15],
           CASE
               WHEN 16
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [16],
           CASE
               WHEN 17
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [17],
           CASE
               WHEN 18
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [18],
           CASE
               WHEN 19
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [19],
           CASE
               WHEN 20
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [20],
           CASE
               WHEN 21
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [21],
           CASE
               WHEN 22
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [22],
           CASE
               WHEN 23
                    BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, date1) AND DATEPART(HOUR, date2) - 1 THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS [23]
    FROM @t
) t;
```

**Output:**

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: The issue with this is that if the hours roll over midnight, it will not work as expected.  Would your data set have results like this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some questions about the data sample that you have provided.
It's not entirely clear how each hour is selected. Is is an hour gets selected if number of minutes an item was active is greater than some number? There is also a possible issue with CompletedDate being on the next day. In either case here is one more example how to achieve this. You will have to tinker with the hour logic to get the answer you need.

```
DECLARE @data Table
(
    id int identity(1,1)
    ,ReadyDate datetime
    ,CompletedDate datetime
    ,foo varchar(500)
)
INSERT INTO @data
VALUES

('10-14-2019 06:05','10-14-2019 06:10','(this will populate no columns)')
,('10-14-2019 07:12','10-14-2019 09:30','(this will populate the 7:00 hour and 8:00 hour)')
,('10-14-2019 10:02','10-14-2019 13:55','(this will populate the 10:00 hour, 11:00, 12:00)')
,('10-14-2019 12:50','10-14-2019 15:30','(this will populate the 12:00, 13:00, 14:00)') 

;
;WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number+1
        FROM Numbers 
        WHERE Number < 24
)
,src
as (
Select *, 
    flag = CASE WHEN Number >= DATEPART(hour, ReadyDate) AND Number < DATEPART(hour, ReadyDate) + DateDiff(hour, ReadyDate, CompletedDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
from @Data
    CROSS APPLY Numbers
)
Select * 
from src
    PIVOT 
    (
        max(flag) for number in ([1],[2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24])
    ) as ptable
```